# Discord HTML meta tags for thumbnail embedded image

Tags: html, meta-tags

I am trying to optimize my `<meta>` tags to work properly on social media such as Discord.

What I got so far:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="og:image" content="URL">
```

This will display a big image on discord, but I need a thumbnail sized image too.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="URL">
```

This would be the thumbnail.

How can I have a big image and a thumbnail using `<meta>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For social media embeds, you can sets the specific width and height of the image so that it displays accordingly using `og:image` properties.

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="path_to_image.png">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="250">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="250">
```

You can also set the colour to display for some platforms such as Discord with the `theme-color` property.

```html
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFFFFF">
```

Comment: Is it also possible to have 2 images? One as Thumbnail and one as Image

Comment: Not exactly, you can only deliver one image via meta properties, the only other time this occurs is if the page itself contains is a path to an image itself.

Answer (score 5):

If you want images to be displayed in a large format you have to provide twitter meta tags

I tried the example in the other answer using only openGraph tags but this is the result:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Hello World">
<meta property="og:description" content="Lorem ipsum sit dolor">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/hello-world">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/hello-world/thumbnail.png">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
```

[image]

As you can see only a small icon is shown, but after inspecting other websites that where displaying large thumbnails, I saw that they included twitter:card, So I tried including it and now my links display large thumbnails instead of just the small icon.

```html
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@twitter_handle">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Hello World">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Lorem ipsum sit dolor">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://www.example.com/hello-world/thumbnail.png">
```

So full example:
[image]

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Hello World">
<meta property="og:description" content="Lorem ipsum sit dolor">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/hello-world">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/hello-world/thumbnail.png">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="My Website">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Hello World">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Lorem ipsum sit dolor">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://www.example.com/hello-world/thumbnail.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FD0054">
```

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/markup

> twitter:image
>
> URL of image to use in the card. Images must be less than 5MB in size.
> JPG, PNG, WEBP and GIF formats are supported. Only the first frame of
> an animated GIF will be used. SVG is not supported.twitter:image
>
> URL of image to use in the card. Images must be less than 5MB in size.
> JPG, PNG, WEBP and GIF formats are supported. Only the first frame of
> an animated GIF will be used. SVG is not supported.

Facebook recommends image size of 1200x630 for open graph